# How to upload image to media library? (No upload field)

Tags: media, files

I'm missing something in media_library. When I click "Add media" in the media library (/media/add/image) there's no browse/upload field.

All of the other media types have an upload field.

This document in the [Drupal Media Guide](https://drupal-media.gitbooks.io/drupal8-guide/content/modules/media/adding-media-items.html#images) seems to imply that there should be an upload field.

[image: Screen shot of add media image page with no upload field]

Comment: I opened another Drupal instance that I had on my development machine, and found it to correctly include the file upload widget in the form. Hrmph.

Comment: On my faulty project, I tried uninstalling everything related to images and media, and re-enabled media_library, to no avail. I'll attempt to build a fresh site from scratch tomorrow and see if I can discover what makes the file upload field vanish from media/add/image

Comment: I used the opportunity to do some debugging with PHPStorm, and was able to set breakpoints and watch the control flow a bit. I never found a smoking gun that was prohibiting the file upload field from being added to the /media/add/image form. I rebuilt the project from scratch, and I've managed not to lose the file upload field since then. There was clearly some interaction that made it vanish, but discovering what will have to wait for another day.